# center div with position absolute with just css without knowing the width

Tags: html, css

I would like to center different images which are shown and hidden, depending on how the user clicks.
What I did to center an image was:

```
img { 
  margin-left: auto; 
  margin-right: auto; 
  display: block;
}
```

which worked fine. But it does not work for a `position: absolute;` Is there a css only way to center a `position: absolute` div horizontally in the middle of `body` or `parent` without knowing the `width`?

Comment: add `text-align: center;` to its container, and make the container position absolute instead of the image.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For absolutely positioned element, you can set the `margin:auto` in combination with `left:0` and `right:0` (for horizontally centered) or `top:0` and `bottom:0` (for vertically centered):

```
img {
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  margin:auto;
}
```

### [Demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/hH85x/)

Comment: how simple it can be. Thank you very much!

Comment: @supersize you're welcome, yes it's simple but looks like it's not more popular/well-known than the solution using `translateX(-50%)`, which also works.

Comment: No idea why this solution is not that advertised, the `translate` solution isn't that great if you consider browser support.

Comment: @Andrei exactly. I assume this is the best and simplest solution. I didn't know as well.

Comment: @Andrei yes, although the old browsers (which don't support transform) will be gone soon.

Comment: BTW, I would like to reveal that, I've known of the transform trick (to center absolutely positioned element) before knowing about this trick. It's really surprising.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/hH85x/2/ it does not need a width, you have to put it on the img not on the div :)

Answer (score 1):

Give the element `position: absolute` and position it 50% from the `left` edge of the screen, then use `transform: translate` to move it *50% of its width* to the left.

### Demo:

HTML:

```
<div class="center"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.center {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

[Here's a pen](http://codepen.io/Mest/pen/bfFyu?editors=110) with this.

[Here's the browser support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d) for 2d transforms, and information about which vendor prefixes you need.

You can also use `transform: translate3d` to center elements vertically with the same logic. The CSS would then look like this:

```
.center {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;  
  transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way i know is using an additional div, like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/tTAG5/1/

HTML:

```
<div class="target">
<div class="wrapper"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background:blue;
    margin:0 auto;
    margin-left:-50%;
}
.target{
    position:absolute;
    left:50%;
}
```

What this does is:

- set `left:50%` on your main `div`
- add your `div`s contents in another *wrapper* `div` element like shown in demo above
- set `margin-left:-50%` on the *wrapper* `div`

Answer (score -1):

You can use:

```
padding-left: 50%;
margin-left: -(half the width of your image)px
```

It's not the cleanest solution it's probably not the right scenario for absolute positioning.

Comment: he doesn't know the width

Comment: it is a good scenario, but only if you know the `width` of an element. As my OP said I want it without knowing the width.

Comment: Yeah without knowing the width it's not a good scenario. Could you post a fiddle of your problem in the OP?